# Odd array_merge_recursive behavior with string keys

Tags: php, arrays, merge

I'm trying to use [`array_merge_recursive`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php) to merge two data structures.

```
<?php
$testSite = array(
    'name' => 'test site',
    'modules' => array(
        'foo' => 'true',
        'bar' => 'true'
    )
);
$testData = array(
    'modules' => array(
        'bar' => 'false'
    )
);

$testSite = array_merge_recursive($testSite, $testData);
```

*Note that I'm using strings instead of booleans for debug printing purposes*

I would expect `$testSite` to be the exact same after this code has ran, except for the `modules.bar` property, which I'd expect to see being changed to `false`. What happens instead, as seen in this [**live example**](http://codepad.org/2oa9Ms4p), is that `bar` is turned into an array containing it's old value and the value `false` is appended to that.

The documentation page reads that this is what will happen for numeric keys, but these are all strings keys. Can anyone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want [`array_replace_recursive`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace-recursive.php).

[`array_merge_recursive()` vs. `array_replace_recursive()`](http://jontai.me/blog/2011/12/array_merge_recursive-vs-array_replace_recursive/)

Comment: I sure do! Thanks a lot. If you don't mind, I added to your answer an article I found detailing the differences.